# RSpec records attribute doesn't update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

Trying to test if making a Vote on an Answer updates its score.
The score updates but its not the same object that gets tested.
( Every Vote has its own voteable Answer object, with same .id)
Therefore the spec fails.

**PRY console during rspec testing:**

```
> Answer.first
=> #<Answer:0x000000087b6418 id: 1, (...) score: 2>
> answer
=> #<Answer:0x000000081bea88 id: 1, (...) score: 0>
```

**vote_spec.rb**

```
answer ||= FactoryGirl.create(:answer)
vote = FactoryGirl.create(:vote, like: true, user_id: 1, voteable_id: answer.id, voteable_type: "Answer")
vote2 = FactoryGirl.create(:vote, like: true, user_id: 2, voteable_id: answer.id, voteable_type: "Answer")
vote3 = FactoryGirl.create(:vote, like: true, user_id: 3, voteable_id: answer.id, voteable_type: "Answer")
vote4 = FactoryGirl.create(:vote, user_id: 4, voteable_id: answer.id, voteable_type: "Answer")

expect(answer.score).to eq(2)
```

**vote.rb**

```
  after_create :set_voteable_score

  private

  def set_voteable_score
    self.voteable.update_column(:score, count_score(self.voteable))
    true
    binding.pry
  end

  def count_score(voteable)
    votes = voteable.votes.all
    votes.where(like: true).count - votes.where(like: false).count
  end
```

So if I check the vote.voteable.score with all vote(vote, vote2, vote3...), each returns a different voteable object, and the answer in vote_spec.rb doesn't get updated.

Why is this behaviour ( more than 1 record with same id exists)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the voteables have the same id, they're all the same records. What you have then, probably, is different *instances* of the record, which have been loaded from the db at different times.

Try this:

```
expect(answer.reload.score).to eq(2)
```